# update script is not working?

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner in php. I am trying to make an web application where users score is updated for every correct answer he answers.
The script is as below

```
<?php
$username="surendra";
$useranswer=$_REQUEST['option'];
$qno=$_REQUEST['a'];

  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gk");
```

// Check connection

```
  include('connection.php');
    $sql1="SELECT * FROM questions  WHERE  qid=$qno";
    $result=mysql_query($sql1);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $correctanswer=$row['answer'];

}

   include('connection.php');
     $sql1="SELECT * FROM contest  WHERE  username LIKE '".$username."'";
     $result=mysql_query($sql1);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $points=$row['points'];

}   

    if ($username=$correctanswer)
      {
         $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gk");
          // Check connection
       if (mysqli_connect_errno())
         {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          }

        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE contest SET points=$points+5
         WHERE username =$username");

          mysqli_close($con);
         }

  ?>
```

---

The update function is not working pls help me in this?

Comment: mysql_*() functions are deprecrated and you have huge security flaws in your script (sql injections) that could get you in trouble.

Comment: that code is horrible and very racy, as well as highly likely to be vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Also has a pretty distinct cargo-cult programming smell about it. Looks like you're selecting based on primary key fields, yet use while loops to retrieve what will most likely only ever be a single row of data.

Comment: [Please, don't use mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) in new code. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [_prepared statements_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statementhttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Answer (score 1):

try to enclose `$username` in single quotation marks:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE contest SET points=$points+5 WHERE username = '$username'");
```

And `if ($username==$correctanswer)` like the others posted.

Then I recommend you to learn how to bind params and work with prepared statements.
Read [here](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `=` sign

```
if ($username=$correctanswer)
           --^
```

Try:

```
if ($username == $correctanswer)
```

Also, `$username` needs to be quoted:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE contest SET points = $points + 5 WHERE username ='".$username."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

you have `include('connection.php');` twice in your code.

`if ($username=$correctanswer)` should be `==`.

Consider using mysqli_ functions or PDO and protect your code against SQL injection.